# How to check the battery health of a Magic Mouse 2?

Tags: battery, mouse, bluetooth, macos

No I do not want to see the 'percent charge' left (which is all that gets returned when trying to google this)

In the same way as you can see the 'battery health' for an iPhone, I would like to see this for the Magic Mouse 2 (the one with the charging slot underneath with an embedded, non removable battery)

Comment: Battery Health doesn’t exist for peripheral devices.

Comment: The 'question already has answers here' does not answer the question. It's a different question.

Comment: Did you read the comment?:

Comment: Perhaps linking to a technical article that explains what you consider to be battery health this might gather some reopen votes? Assuming people understand a topic often means close as dupe here. Demonstrating technical accuracy often is rewarded with good discussion and answers